# CSS - Select the first matched elements (not the first child or the first type)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select the first `.choose` div in a selector and the second `.choose` div in another selector from this HTML code.
I don't want `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` but something like this `:nth-of-class()` or     `:nth-of-selected()`

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div></div>
  <div class='elements'></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='elements'></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**note:** I know ho to do it in javascript and jquery but I want an answer in css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no selector to match the first child/sibling with a certain class. If you need it for this specific HTML structure only, then could use something like `#parent > .elements ~ .elements` to specifically target that second one.

```css
#parent > .elements { /* for all .elements children */
  background: red;
}
#parent > .elements ~ .elements { /* only those that are siblings
                                     of a previous .elements element */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Foo</div>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Bar</div>
  <div>---</div>
</div>
```

Edit, regarding Mihai T’s hint that if there’s more .elements children it would not only affect the second one, this can be fixed by adding to the first selector, this way:

```css
#parent > .elements, /* for all .elements children */
#parent > .elements ~ .elements ~ .elements { /* and all that have at least two .elements before them */
  background: red;
}
#parent > .elements ~ .elements { /* only those that are siblings
                                     of a previous .elements element */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Foo</div>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Bar</div>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Foo</div>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Foo</div>
  <div>---</div>
  <div class='elements'>Foo</div>
  <div>---</div>
</div>
```

Comment: good answer. the problem is that it works only if you have 2 . ( as you said, only for this specific answer ) . Otherwise, it will apply the green background to all the direct children with class `.elements` , except the first one. So not only the second

Comment: @MihaiT good point, but making the first selector `#parent > .elements,
#parent > .elements ~ .elements ~ .elements` instead would easily fix that.

Comment: I think it will not work
what I want is a selector to make the first element `float: right;` and the second element `float: left;` (but they aren't the first and second child or type)

Comment: But it's good I will use it for my problem
thank you :)